# How to share a SharePoint Online site with external users which are not in Azure AD via PowerAutomate or LogicApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, https, external-sharing, logic-app

I'm struggling with a sharing external users. Normally I go to a sharepoint site and search for an external user (e.g. test@gmail.com) then I click share and the persons gets the link without registering. I tried it with the Graph API sharing function, but they need to register and create a guest AD Account, but my workflow needs to have go on and give access for a specific folder.

How I can do that with an http or Connector in PowerAutomate or LogicApps?

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

As to share SharePoint site to external user via Power Automate, you could refer this answer:
[SharePoint Site External Sharing using Power Automate](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/SharePoint-Site-External-Sharing-using-Power-Automate/td-p/1311801)

Comment: I want to share a specific folder with a specific external user name and not an already existing user. Maybe this is a misunderstanding.